# Vimeo api node for upload videos return error "source object may only be an instance of Buffer or Readable in this environment"

Tags: node.js, vimeo, vimeo-api

Before cd everything, I'll discard possible error points:

1 - My acount is Premium and has permission to upload videos via the api:

[image]

2 - I've tried using other file formats, such as blob, but I get another error basically saying that it's not possible to find the location of the file;

I'm trying to get a file through a form and send it to vimeo via vimeo-api in Node;

Anyway, here's the implementation of my code:

**Front-end with call my endpoint:**

```
    const startUploadFinal = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('video_file', currentFile);

    localhost.post('vimeo/blob', formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
        access_token: `voitto-token ${localStorage.getItem('oauth_token')}`
      }
    });
   };
```

**Router for my endpoint:**

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import Vimeo from '../../app/controller/vimeoController';
import AuthMiddleware from '../../app/middleware/auth';
import upload from '../../config/multerConfig';

const routes = new Router();

routes.post(
  '/vimeo',
  upload.single('video_file'),
  AuthMiddleware,
  Vimeo.upload
);

export default routes;
```

**Upload config with multex:**

```
import multer from 'multer';

const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage });

module.exports = upload;
```

**My endpoint:**

```
async upload(req, res) {
 const client = new Vimeo(client_id, client_secret, fixedToken);
 console.log('File:', req.file);
 console.log('Size file:', req.file.size);
 client.upload(
  req.file,
  {
    name: 'Testing',
    description: 'Tescription Testing',
    'upload.size': req.file.size,
    'upload.approach': 'tus',
  },
  function (uri) {
    console.log('File upload completed. Your Vimeo URI is:', uri);
  },
  function (bytesUploaded, bytesTotal) {
    const percentage = ((bytesUploaded / bytesTotal) * 100).toFixed(2);
    console.log(bytesUploaded, bytesTotal, `${percentage}%`);
  },
  function (error) {
    console.log(`${error}`);
  }
 );
}
```

**Print data at endpoint and final error:**

[image]

Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to upload an object when the source code will only allow for buffers, buffers are photos/videos just written in binary to make it easier for the computer to read.
Simple Fix:

```js
client.upload(
    req.file.buffer,
    ...
}
```

Full Example:

```js
async function upload(req, res) {
   const client = new Vimeo(client_id, client_secret, fixedToken);
   console.log('File:', req.file);
   console.log('Size file:', req.file.size);
   client.upload(
       req.file.buffer,
       {
           name: 'Testing',
            description: 'Tescription Testing',
            'upload.size': req.file.size,
            'upload.approach': 'tus',
       },
       function (uri) {
           console.log('File upload completed. Your Vimeo URI is:', uri);
       },
       function (bytesUploaded, bytesTotal) {
           const percentage = ((bytesUploaded / bytesTotal) * 100).toFixed(2);
           console.log(bytesUploaded, bytesTotal, `${percentage}%`);
       },
       function (error) {
           console.log(`${error}`);
       }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tyler2P, but it doesn't work and I get new errors, as shown in the image below:

https://i.imgur.com/7tDn7aa.png

Comment: @AndersonAmorim The error is not caused in the code you have provided, please provide more of the code above for me to help you.

Comment: This is all the code that involves the upload, I can add the HTML from the frontend in React, but it's basically an input file. I don't know what else I can offer to help, what more would you need?

Comment: @AndersonAmorim I have edited my answer that should hopefully fix your problem, if not unfortunately the error s not caused as a result of the code I have provided.

Comment: I added the routes file of my api in exoress in the question, sometimes it can help...

Comment: thanks for the help, unfortunately the code provided doesn't really solve the problem and you keep getting the error: i.imgur.com/7tDn7aa.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/vimeo-upload-client

```
uploadFromBinary(params = {
    video: Buffer.alloc(8),
    name: 'video name',
    description: 'video desc',
    folder: ''
}){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var video = params.video,
            name = params.name,
            description = params.description,
            folder = params.folder;

        axios.post('https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos', {
            "upload": {
                "approach": "tus",
                "size": video.byteLength
            },
            "name": name ? name : undefined,
            "description": description ? description : undefined
        }, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${this.accessToken}`
            }
        }).then(res => {
            
            var vimeoVideoID = res.data.uri.split('/')[2];
            
            console.log('Vimeo video ID: '+vimeoVideoID);

            UploadVideoTusJs(res.data.upload.upload_link, video)
            .then(res => {

                if(folder){
                    axios.put(`https://api.vimeo.com/me/projects/${folder}/videos/${vimeoVideoID}`,{}, {
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${this.accessToken}`
                        }})
                        .then(response => {
                            console.log(response);
                            resolve(response);

                        }).catch(err => {
                            console.log(err);
                            reject(err);
                        });
                }else{
                    resolve(res);
                }

            }).catch(err => {
                reject(err);
            });

        }).catch(err => {
            reject(err);
        });

    });
}
```

> I Have same problem I wrote custom POST request using axios

- using this vimeo API https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos and pass buffer